# Weasyprint not printing the pages spanning over more than one page

Tags: html, css, pdf, weasyprint

**strong text**[image]

this is the code I am using to convert a rendered html page to pdf.

```
html_string = render_to_string("monthly_report/generated_pdf.html",
                                       {'form': form, 'month': monthStr.strftime("%B %Y")})
        html = HTML(string=html_string)
        main_doc = html.render()
        pdf = main_doc.write_pdf()
        return HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
```

The row having data spanning over more than one page is being truncated and data is getting lost.
**What I want is the remaining data should be printed on the next page.**
How it can be achieved ???
Please help, I am stuck over it from yesterday.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is caused by [bug #36](https://github.com/Kozea/WeasyPrint/issues/36), WeasyPrint is not able to split table cells yet.

Comment: thnks for ur reply. Is there any workaround for this ??